# module.exports is not a function nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Quoting only the important parts of the code.
This is my `server.js` in the node backend server

```
//routes
const userapi = require('./api/routes/user');
//models
require('./api/models/userModel');

//use routes
userapi(app);
```

on my `userapi` which is my routes I call my `userController`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    module.exports = function (app) {
        var userCtrl = require('../controllers/userCtrl');

        app.post('/api/validate_user', function(req, res, next){
            userCtrl.validate_user(req, res);
        });
    }
})();
```

and this is my userController code. In the future, i will write a code that will handle all the transaction from my MongoDB.

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    model = mongoose.model('users'),
    brcpyt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function() {
    return {

        validate_user: function(req, res) {

            console.log('here');
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is, everytime I make a http request from my frontend. I get an error that says `userCtrl.validate_user` is not a function. My frontend can access the endpoints of `'/api/validate_user'` and the `var userCtrl = require('../controllers/userCtrl')` is a correct file path, but everytime that I type `userCtrl` to my routes it does not give me function `validate_user`

[image: validate_user is not on the list]

[image: its located]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to be wrapping your modules in IIFEs. That said, the issue you are seeing specifically is because your userCtrl module is exporting a function that, when called, returns an object which will then have a `validate_user` member -- it's not exporting an object directly. Try checking the value of `typeof userCtrl` - it'll be `function` instead of an `object`, which is what you're expecting here :)

Specifically, the following should work with no changes to userCtrl:

`var userCtrl = require('../controllers/userCtrl')()`

Notice the extra parenthesis at the end? That will invoke the exported function and give you back an object with a `validate_user` method. This pattern is sometimes used when you'd like to pass some options to the module, like a factory pattern. For example,

`const userCtrlFactory = require('../controllers/userCtrl')
const userCtrl = userCtrlFactory({ option: value })`

This, however, is not the best way to do so, you would be using classes for that.

I recommend you drop the IIFEs from your code (`(function () {})()`) and just have a top-level `module.exports` (like you did with the userCtrl) that exports either an object or a class, depending on what you need from it. For userCtrl, just export an object directly as you're not passing options or have a need for "instantiating" a controller more than once:

`'use strict';
module.exports = {
  validate_user: ...
};`

Answer (score 1):

require gives you the value assigned to module.exports, so your code is like:

```
var userCtrl = function() {
    return {

        validate_user: function(req, res) {

            console.log('here');
        }
    }
};

userCtrl.validate_user(...);
```

Do you see the bug now? userCtrl is a function, and therefore doesn't have a validate_user property ...

Comment: i see it now. so all i have to do is module.exports  = {  ..my functions.. }